# Finding limit of $\frac{\sin\pi3^x}{x}$ as $x\to 0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to find the limit of $\frac{\sin\pi3^x}{x}$ as $x\to 0$ using ONLY notable limits
please help me.

Comment: Do you know l'Hopital's rule? Or at least $\lim_{x\to0}\sin(x)/x=1$?

Comment: I don't know l'hopital rule yet but I know all notable limits

Comment: You can't use $\frac{\sin x}x$ , since $3^0$ is $1$, not $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin x=\sin(\pi-x)\quad,\quad\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1\quad,\quad\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(a)\iff$ $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi\cdot3^x)}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi-\pi\cdot3^x)}x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi-\pi\cdot3^x)}{\pi-\pi\cdot3^x}\cdot\frac{\pi-\pi\cdot3^x}{x}=$$ $$=\pi\cdot\lim_{x\to0}1\cdot\frac{1-3^x}x=-\pi\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{3^x-3^0}{x-0}=-\pi\cdot(3^x)'_{x=0}=-\pi\cdot(3^x\cdot\ln3)_{x=0}=-\pi\cdot\ln3.$$

Comment: You forgot a minus sign somewhere. For $x=0.001$ the value I get is $-3.45328$.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the fact that $\sin\alpha=-\sin(\alpha-\pi)$, so we can rewrite the limit as
$$
\lim_{x\to0}-\frac{\sin(\pi(3^x-1))}{x}=
-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi(3^x-1))}{\pi(3^x-1)}\frac{\pi(3^x-1)}{x}
$$
The limits of the two fractions are known limits. The original limit is $-\pi\log3$.

Using the chain rule for computing the derivative of the numerator is much more instructive, in my opinion.

Comment: There is one standard formula $\sin(\pi-y)=\sin y$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Yes, but the one I used poses less problems with the signs later on. See Lucian's mistake (before correction).

Answer (score 1):

For $x\to0, \; \operatorname{e}^x\sim 1+x+o(x^2)$ so that $3^x\sim 1+x\ln 3$
$$
\frac{\sin(\pi \operatorname{3}^x)}{x}\sim
\frac{\sin(\pi +\pi x\ln 3)}{x}=-\pi\ln3\frac{\sin(\pi x\ln 3)}{\pi x\ln 3}\to-\pi\ln3
$$

Comment: This answer's based on the Taylor series for the exponential. Why would this be allowed if l'Hospital isn't? Perhaps it is, though...

Comment: Sorry I also meant taylor series

Comment: @alexjo: You mean $x \to 0$ instead of $\to \infty$ in the first place?

Comment: Actually it's just based on the knowledge of the notable limit $$ \frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$$

Comment: and on the fact that you can substitute inside the sin function.. this may actually be not trivial to affirm